# function that only returns specified column with getSymbols()

Tags: r, quantmod

So i was trying to build this simple function that only returns adjusted price on google using getSymbols().

```
yahoo<-function(a){
a<-getSymbols("a", from= as.Date("1/1/13", format="%m/%d/%y"),to=Sys.time(), auto.assign = FALSE)
a[,6]
```

}

However, this literally gets Symbol that is named a or x whatever it is.
i was expecting something like yahoo(GOOG) will return google's adjusted price. 
Any idea how i can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If we need to return the values, then get `substitute` the argument and deparse it to a string

```
library(quantmod)   
yahoo <- function(a){
   a <- deparse(substitute(a))
    res <- getSymbols(a, from= as.Date("1/1/13", 
           format="%m/%d/%y"),to=Sys.time(), auto.assign = FALSE)
    res[,6]

  }

out <- yahoo(GOOG)
head(out)
#           GOOG.Adjusted
#2013-01-02      359.2882
#2013-01-03      359.4968
#2013-01-04      366.6006
#2013-01-07      365.0010
#2013-01-08      364.2807
#2013-01-09      366.6751

tail(out)
#           GOOG.Adjusted
#2018-02-13       1052.10
#2018-02-14       1069.70
#2018-02-15       1089.52
#2018-02-16       1094.80
#2018-02-20       1102.46
#2018-02-21       1111.34
```

---

Another option would be using `tidyquant` and `tidyverse` libraries

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyquant)
yahoo2 <- function(a) {
      a <- quo_name(enquo(a))
      tq_get(a, from = "2013-01-01", to = Sys.Date()) %>%
          select(date, adjusted)
 }  

yahoo2(GOOG)
# A tibble: 1,294 x 2
#   date       adjusted
#   <date>        <dbl>
# 1 2013-01-02      359
# 2 2013-01-03      359
# 3 2013-01-04      367
# 4 2013-01-07      365
# 5 2013-01-08      364
# 6 2013-01-09      367
# 7 2013-01-10      368
# 8 2013-01-11      368
# 9 2013-01-14      359
#10 2013-01-15      360
# ... with 1,284 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `assign` will do it.

```
assign('AAPL',getSymbols(‘AAPL,from='2018-02-01',auto.assign = F)[,6] )
```

If you want to do this in a function:

```
yahoo <- function(ticker, from){
  assign(ticker,
         getSymbols(ticker,from=from,auto.assign = F)[,6],
         pos = 1
         )
}
yahoo(‘AAPL’)
```

Be aware that some Yahoo tickers are using special characters like `^` or `@` that will be removed/replaced (i.e. "^GSPC”). You have more flexibility with the non-function method in naming your objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the quantmod functions Op(), Hi(), Lo(), Cl() and Ad()
For example like this:

```
a <- Ad(getSymbols("a", from= as.Date("1/1/13", format="%m/%d/%y"),to=Sys.time(), auto.assign = FALSE))
```